# Can't proceed with installing Magento by executing bin/magento config:set command

Tags: magento2, installation, magento2.4.1

I try to install Magento 2 and create/configure a new magento project.

Steps:

1. Executed command:

   bin/magento setup:install \

   > ```
   > --backend-frontname=backend \
   > --amqp-host=rabbitmq \
   > --amqp-port= \
   > --amqp-user= \
   > --amqp-password= \
   > --db-host=db \
   > --db-name= \
   > --db-user=magento \
   > --db-password= \
   > --http-cache-hosts=varnish:80 \
   > --session-save=redis \
   > --session-save-redis-host=redis \
   > --session-save-redis-port=6379 \
   > --session-save-redis-db=2 \
   > --session-save-redis-max-concurrency=20 \
   > --cache-backend=redis \
   > --cache-backend-redis-server=redis \
   > --cache-backend-redis-db=0 \
   > --cache-backend-redis-port=6379 \
   > --page-cache=redis \
   > --page-cache-redis-server=redis \
   > --page-cache-redis-db=1 \
   > --page-cache-redis-port=6379
   > ```
2. Executed command >> **bin/magento config:set** --lock-env web/unsecure/base_url "https://${TRAEFIK_SUBDOMAIN}.${TRAEFIK_DOMAIN}/"

***Step 2 failed*** with the following result:

There are no commands defined in the "config" namespace.

Did you mean one of these?
app:config
module:config
setup:config
setup:store-config

When executing command **php bin/magento list** I get a list of available commands in Magento CLI 2.4.1 but the config commands are missing.

I did some research on the internet but couldn't find a solution for this. Can someone please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Magento 2 it's mandatory to install first ElasticSearch. After installing elasticsearch the install of Magento 2 went succesfull.

Answer (score 3):

It seems your installation was not completed, please check if the DB pointed in the setup install command has been populated with all the tables. If the tables are populated you might be missing install timestamp in `app/etc/env.php`, please check if you have install node populated properly in there, it should be something like below;

```
'install' => [
        'date' => 'Mon, 14 Jan 2019 15:13:48 +0000'
    ]
```

Comment: I checked env.php in etc map and indeed the install node is missing.

Comment: I updated my question with the complete setup install command

Comment: How to check if the DB pointed in the setup install command has been populated with all the tables? As you said I am missing the install timestamp in app/etc/env.php

Comment: I would not know your complete required installation configuration as it is environment-based, but you can get started with a good starting point here -  https://meetanshi.com/blog/install-magento-2-4-via-command-line